# Assembly start function x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64

At the start of a function there is this construction:

```
0x7ffff7e47a10: test   $0xf,%spl
0x7ffff7e47a14: je     0x7ffff7e47a1b
0x7ffff7e47a1a: int3
```

What is the purpose of the flag `0xf` in `spl` if it doesn't do interrupting? 
Is is something like "all is OK with stack"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This checks if the stack is aligned to 16 bytes and aborts the program if it is not. Iff the stack is aligned to 16 bytes, the least four bits of `%rsp` and by extension `%spl` are clear. This is what `test $0xf,%spl` tests for.

Comment: @Toby Please do not “correct” mistakes that are not mistakes. Please look up the word “iff” before editing it to the less correct “if.”

Comment: Sorry, I thought if it was a code construct it would be formatted as such (it's not English AFAIK?). Maybe you could clarify more in the answer as there are lots of very different results for an "iff" google search. I take your point, but anyone not immediately familiar with "iff" will also think it a typo and so will not understand the value of it